# Nightmare inside then cant use pdf

Tags: javascript, nightmare

the code:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({show:true});

nightmare
  .goto('https://duckduckgo.com')
  .evaluate(() => { return document.title; })
  .end()
  .then((title) => {
    console.log(title);
    nightmare.pdf(title, {printBackground: true});
  });
```

Why it isn't saving the pdf with "title"? And even if I change the title to some string like `pdf.pdf` it still doesn't work inside `.then()` why is that?

Comment: yes, correct folder. The `nightmare.pdf` doesn't work, it think that it doesn't even execute.

Comment: does the `console.log(title);` work? Do you get any console errors? From what I can see in the docs, in the options for the nightmare.pdf you can specify a callback which will contain an error message in its response, if one is generated. have you tried that?

Comment: yes `console.log(title);` displays the right title, no console errors, `nightmare.pdf` does nothing... tried the error callback no output at all, data/error are not displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out why it was happening:

The `.end()` was causing the other functions not to work inside `.then`, after moving it **inside** `.then` it started working as needed. Code:

```
nightmare
  .goto('https://duckduckgo.com')
  .evaluate(() => { return document.title; })
  //.end() // <= this one is bad
  .then(function (title) {
    console.log(title);
    nightmare.end() // <= This one is good.
    return nightmare.pdf(title, {printBackground: true});
  })
```